# Map job only using one processor in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Do map functions in Apache Spark only use one processor? I would like to parallelize my map procedures across 8 CPUs, but when I run "top" I only see one processor at work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I am using Python.

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Answer (score 2):

Top possibilities:

1. Your data has only one partition, because it's small. One partition of data gets handled by one task, hence one core. This is good and normal. You can try `repartition` but it's probably wasteful to shuffle just to make partitions if your data set is tiny.
2. You specified `local` master instead of `local[*]` when running locally
3. You're actually seeing some long-running non-distributed method call on your driver take a long time, not the `map`, and that's of course not parallel